# Is it possible to get the assembly information of the client who connects to your .NET Remoting server?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, .net-assembly, .net-remoting

Is it possible to get the assembly information (I'm really only interested in getting the version of the connected assembly) of a client who is connected to our.NET Remoting service? I am able to get the IPAddress of the client, which I can also use to get the machine name over the network as well, but I haven't been able to find out how to get any other information from the client machine beyond those. Solutions that involve having to update the client unfortunately won't work, unless it involves only modifying the app.config file, in which case that would be an acceptable solution.

Also, if this is something that is possible to do with WCF and not .NET Remoting, let me know because I may be able to use this as some good leverage to finally get us away from Remoting.

Thanks in advance for any help with this! As an FYI, we normally build against .NET 4.0, but also have legacy packages running 3.5 SP1 and 2.0.

*EDIT* Forgot to mention, we are making remoting to a shared interface which is visible to both the client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't believe this is possible.  You would need to have the client send that information in a method call.  I can see why this would be really handy, but I don't believe any of the assembly version information is sent in the TCP/HTTP headers.

Comment: Hmm... I did a bit of research after posting this question, and one would think it would be possible since when making calls to remote assemblies it checks the assembly version. I'm not sure if this still happens though if you are remoting through a shared interface (I read a few articles saying that assembly versioning isn't an issue when remoting over a shared interface, but don't know how this affects the communication process.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly(v=vs.100).aspx

I wonder if calling Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() might work?

Comment: Though it doesn't seem to be serializable... wonder if there's a way around that...